# Hiding desktop icons in a custom Kali live ISO with gnome

Tags: kali-linux, gnome, dconf, xdg-user-dirs

I built for fun and convenience a portable customized Kali live ISO with gnome that I can carry easily around on my USB pen. I am struggling on two very stupid and useless things that, anyway, I would like to fix just for the sake of completeness.

The one I am asking in here is about hiding the desktop icons that get automatically shown in the Desktop (home directory gets expanded in the desktop).

Some more details:

- Kali 6.1.0-kali9-amd64
- Gnome version 44.0
- I use persistence for `/home` and for `/opt`, so all `~/.config` and user configurations will be persisted, while changes to `/usr`, `/etc` and so on can be easily changed in the build process of the iso.

I tried to play with both `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and `dconf-editor` without any real success.

Comment: Are you aware that Kali is a special purpose distribution intended for experts? (https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/330217) A general purpose distribution might be easier to customize. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/1089610/1186757 (a bit old) or https://www.maketecheasier.com/hide-desktop-icons-ubuntu/ Of course you can try if the suggested solutions are applicable to Kali. Please [edit] your question and add details how exactly you "tried to play with both `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and `dconf-editor`".

Comment: Fully aware. In my humble experience, Kali is very handy as a USB live. Being a live usb, I don't use it everyday, I need it in a fat32 partition (<4GB), I managed to customize it to my portable needs including only the tools I need for work and fun when I am around. Honestly, it's working nicely for me, I just miss two stupid things that I was curious to fix, but, doesn't matter much.
Sure, I will add more details of what I tried.

Comment: "*Kali is very handy as a USB live*" Does this not apply to e.g. Ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't very well due to the stripped parts: "my humble experience" and "the tools I need", something I wouldn't want to bore you with here since it's not the aim of the post. I did something similar already with Ubuntu and Debian for fun and this is de facto my preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understood the problem by chance.

`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` was causing the issue since the default `$HOME/Desktop` folder was missing in my `$HOME` folder and somehow the `xdg-user-dirs-update` script must have used the `$HOME` folder itself by default for the desktop icons.

Creating an empty `Desktop` folder and fixing the path in the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` as `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"` fixed it for good. Not the perfect solution (the "show-desktop-icons" setting in `dconf-editor` seemed a better match even though it didn't work in my case) but it does the job.

Not sure if it might help somebody else in the future... I will leave it here just in case.